Trying to match building(s) to lot(s) when data has margin of error in QGIS
I have a set of building and lot GeoJSON data that I want to match and see which buildings sit on which lots.
The problem is that the government data that I obtained has a significant margin of error for its polygon coordinate points, which range from 15cm up to 1.5 meters. Therefore, if I display the building/lot polygon data on QGIS, some buildings are misaligned or bigger than their lots and therefore, when I use the intersects() method in PyQGIS, my function returns inaccurate results.
I have tried to shrink both the lots and the buildings to see if this error is removed, but the same problem persists. I also tried to shrink the buildings only from their centroid by a fixed constant (0.8/0.75) using the geometry by expression option, to account for buildings that are bigger than their lots.
However, while this method has seemingly made the results more accurate, this will not return 100% accurate results, since if I shrink it too much, the intersects() function will miss out on some lots for certain buildings, and if I shrink it too little, some of the buildings will overlap with lots that it is not supposed to. Therefore, shrinking it this way is not a perfect option for me.
I was wondering if there was a way to get completely accurate results for my problem given the margin of error.
Lots are in grey, buildings are in red. Because of how closely packed the lots are together, any slight location error can affect the matching results.

Note the misalignment in the buildings and lots, resulting in them overlapping with the adjacent lots when they likely shouldn't be.


Post is updated. I'm not sure what you mean by 'join the buildings to the plots by the plot with the largest intersecting area', but if you're saying that the lot with the largest intersecting area should be considered to be the only lot that the building is considered to stand on, please note that buildings being on multiple lots in this particular location is valid.

Can you define some area limit for the intersection size by your local knowledge, like "if 100 square meters of a building stands on the second biggest lot then it is ok, but if the intersection is 10 m2 then it is not".

Find the plot with the largest intersecting area with the overlay_intersects() function.
Try the expression:
overlay_intersects(
    layer:='Plot',
    expression:="plotid",
    sort_by_intersection_size:='desc'
    )[0]

Replace 'Plot' with your plot layer name, "plotid" with the attribute you want to extract from that plot.
By sorting the result descending the largest intersection comes first in the resulting array, select the first with [0]
Here I've labeled the buildings with the plot_id, you can also use Field Calculator the create a column.

